# Can the results of one attack of opportunity prevent another?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

In general, can the results of an attack of opportunity (AOO) prevent another AOO if both are triggered by the same exact action? If so, is the prevented AOO already triggered and therefore “spent”, or not?

Specific example #1:

An enemy provokes an AOO from two characters. The first character kills the enemy with their AOO. What happens with the second character? Is their AOO for the round used up now?

Specific example #2:

The Deception subdomain grants the ability "Sudden shift", which allows a cleric to take an immediate action when missed by a melee attack to teleport away "in the blink of an eye".

If two creatures (A and B) want to make an AOO against cleric (C) for some provoking action, then would the cleric be able to blink away from the second AOO if the first one missed? Do both attacks resolve and then the cleric gets the opportunity to use their sudden shift?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, one Attack of Opportunity can potentially prevent another, or make it pointless.

Although Attacks of Opportunity, Immediate Actions and Readied Actions interrupt the flow of combat, they still occur in time order.

There are no rules specifically for order when a creature provokes an attack of opportunity from more than one opponent. However, it's reasonable to assume initiative rules apply:

> If two or more combatants have the same initiative check result, the combatants who are tied act in order of total initiative modifier (highest first). If there is still a tie, the tied characters should roll again to determine which one of them goes before the other.

Once that's been established, have the creatures act in initiative order. If the first to act kills the enemy, then the second character no longer has an opportunity, at least not against a live opponent. There's nothing preventing him from taking his attack of opportunity, but it may be futile.

**Is their AOO for the round used up now?**

Not unless the second creature attacks. The second actor doesn't attempt to attack and then get interrupted. The circumstances change before the attack.

In the case of the immediate action, the rules state:

> Much like a swift action, an immediate action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. However, unlike a swift action, **an immediate action can be performed at any time** — even if it's not your turn. Casting feather fall is an immediate action, since the spell can be cast at any time.

So, once again, if the order of Attacks of Opportunity is determined and the first attacker misses, triggering the cleric's immediate action, then the second creature no longer has an opportunity as the cleric is "away".

And also, once again, the second actor doesn't attempt to attack and then get interrupted. The circumstances change before the attack, so the AoO is not used.

Comment: What about the *“is the prevented AOO ‘lost’ or not?”* part?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie RE: "[A]t least not against a live opponent." I'd let a dude make an attack of opportunity against a creature that died after provoking an attack of opportunity from the dude's ally. However, I think this would be clearer with a header that said *Have creatures take attacks of opportunity in initiative order.* (And, Wyrmwood, consider using [colons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) to introduce information instead of [semicolons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon).)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think the question is getting at whether one’s once-per-turn AoO is consumed in such situations.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You mean, like, *Does a creature who can make an attack of opportunity still expend that attack of opportunity if the creature doesn't make that attack of opportunity?* or something? I guess the question could be read that way, but that's enough of a departure from standard play that I don't think it's incumbent on this answer to read it that way. Ask the question author maybe?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie assuming that AoO's can be prevented, I see the question of whether you see it as a nullification (AoO cannot be attempted, no AoO spent) or interruption (AoO started when trigger was accepted but failed since attack was impossible due to changes in situation.) Difference is in whether or not you see it as the AoO's instantly queueing up when triggered or if AoO's are executed as they come. To me it's just part of the overall question here, which is whether or not AoO's can be interrupted and what happens if/when they are.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Often enough the issue is not knowing how to read a rule to arrive at standard play.

Comment: @Jeutnarg I edited your question to make this element harder to miss. It wasn’t being picked up by every reader.

Comment: Why is it more reasonable to assume immediate actions would follow the same rules as initiative rather than all actions triggering at the same time?

Comment: @zanebrain Combatants never act simultaneously in 3.5. See Initiative. But it is not explicitly covered, so ask your DM.

Comment: @wyrmwood the issue is that this answer depends on AOO'S following the initiative rules. If its not expressly stated and falls under a GM by GM basis the answer doesn't actually work.

Comment: @zanebrain That caveat is in the answer. Do you think it needs further explanation?

Comment: @zanebrain - also, that phrase "It's reasonable to assume" is not mine. It's the one given any time an introduction says something to the effect, *Let’s face it: No set of rules can cover every possible circumstance* like in the intro from the Rules Compendium. GM by GM basis is intrinsic to the game.